# How to display card layout panels when selecting a particular radio button

Tags: extjs

```
 var radioGroup = {
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                layout: 'hbox',
                width: 800,
               items: [{
                  boxLabel: 'Select Time Interval',
                  name: 'timeInterval',
                  id: 'selectTimeInterval',
                  inputValue: 'timeSelector',
                  checked: 'true',
                  handler: function() {
                      //Ext.getCmp('PanelID').layout.setActiveItem('timeIntervalPanel');
                      PanelID.setActiveItem('timeIntervalPanel');
                  }
               },
               {
                  boxLabel: 'Specific Interval',
                  name: 'timeInterval',
                  id: 'specificTimeInterval',
                  inputValue: 'specificInterval',
                  handler: function() {
                      //Ext.getCmp('PanelID').layout.setActiveItem('card-2');
                      PanelID.setActiveItem('card-2');
                  }


               },{

                   boxLabel: 'Last Measurement Collected',
                   name: 'timeInterval',
                   id: 'LastMeasurementCollected',
                   inputValue: 'lastMeasuremnet'

               }]

            };


             var cardPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                 layout: 'card',
                 id: 'PanelID',
                 activeItem: 0,
                 items: [ {
                     itemId: 'timeIntervalPanel',
                     name: 'timeInterval',
                     xtype: 'optima-timeintervalpanel',
                     text: 'select',
                     endDate: new Date(),
                     startDate: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, - 30)
                    },
                     {
                         itemId: 'card-2',
                         html: 'hello2'
                     }
                     ]
             });
```

Comment: currently not displaying proper when panels when selecting a radio field can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with binding, then refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html) for binding on RadioGroup.

Given below is your edited code snippet for displaying one of the panels on radio button selection:

```
items: [{
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            layout: 'hbox',
            width: 800,
            bind: {
                value: '{selectedValue}'
            },
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Select Time Interval',
                name: 'timeInterval',
                inputValue: 'timeSelector',
                checked: 'true',
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Specific Interval',
                name: 'timeInterval',
                id: 'specificTimeInterval',
                inputValue: 'specificInterval',
            }, {

                boxLabel: 'Last Measurement Collected',
                name: 'timeInterval',
                id: 'LastMeasurementCollected',
                inputValue: 'lastMeasuremnet'
            }],
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'card',
            bind: {
                activeItem: '{selectedValue.timeInterval}'
            },
            items: [{
                itemId: 'timeSelector',
                name: 'timeInterval',
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                fieldLabel: 'select',
                endDate: new Date(),
                startDate: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -30)
            }, {
                itemId: 'specificInterval',
                html: 'hello2'
            }, {
                itemId: 'lastMeasuremnet',
                html: 'hello3'
            }]
        }]
```

Check the working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27qb).

Comment: your reference is directing to documentation not with solution.

Comment: I have added a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27qb) for the solution.

Comment: so far best solution for this question.

Comment: @ Surya Prakash Tumma: Thanks! Please cancel the down vote, if possible :)

Comment: i have tried yesterday to make it up but it is locked so to make it up vote Do a small edit on your answer try to paste the significant logic and attach your fiddle

Comment: Usually stack overview doesnt allow undo of vote unless and until there should be an edit to the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort and guiding to post answer in the right format. I have edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch the layout on change event that can be done using below code. 
          `listeners: {
                    change: function() {
                        Ext.getCmp('PanelID').getLayout().setActiveItem(1);
                    }
                }`

I have updated your code in the this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27o0)

Comment: thanks for the solution but not displaying particular card on selction of radio button  i want to show  particular panel on selction of radio button when "select time interval button" is selected i want to show "hello1" and when specific interval is selected have to display "hello2" and when last measurement is selected nothing to display

Comment: can you help me out @SuryaPrakashTumma

Comment: pass the appropriate itemId in place lo number in setActiveitem method ie. setActiveItem('panelItemid')